# Lista en Haskell

Tags: lista, haskell, filtro

Tengo ese ejercicio en Haskell y me explota, no se que me falta modificar, no podemos usar recursividad, entonces lo hice así pero me falla, alguien me pude dar una mano? gracias

```
type Sueldo = Float
type Nombre = String
type Empleado = (Nombre , Sueldo)

nombre :: Empleado-> Nombre
nombre = fst

sueldo :: Empleado -> Sueldo
sueldo = snd

--i) Escribir una función sueldosMayores :: Float -> [Empleado] -> [Sueldo] que, dados
--un monto y una lista de empleados, devuelve la lista de los sueldos mayores al monto.
 
sueldosMayores :: Float -> [Empleado] -> [Sueldo]
sueldosMayores   [] = [] 
sueldosMayores x =  filter (( x <).(sueldo)) []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A veces queda más claro si usas una compresión de listas:

```hs
sueldosMayores :: Float -> [Empleado] -> [Sueldo]
sueldosMayores monto empleados = 
    [s | s <- map sueldo empleados, s > monto]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta erronea la definicion de la funcion sueldosMayores, prueba esto:

```
sueldosMayores :: Float -> [Empleado] -> [Sueldo]
sueldosMayores _ [] = [] 
sueldosMayores x xs = filter ( x <) (map (sueldo) xs)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Nacho

Comment: Te sirvio?  De ser asi te pido que marques la respuesta como correcta!

Comment: Y creo que la linea sueldosMayores _ [] = [] no es necesaria

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio con                                                                                    find :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
pero no se bien como desarrollarlo